# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) , Images are not found?

Tags: angular, api, xampp

I am developping a full stack E commerce web site , but there's a problem loading the images .
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0XcN.png)

there's the path I  made for one image,as an example
[data base screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Xjp.png)

and there's the path in angular project
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnMhT.png)

Comment: Could you share your html file?

Answer (score 0):

As your images show, you're returning the wrong path from DB: you have them in `assets/products/books...` and not in `assets/images/products/books...` as your DB entries are telling. So either change your `image_url` in DB, or create `images` folder under `assets` and move your `products` folder into `images`.